# Angular 2 select <li> and get the text

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

I'm doing an angular2 project and I am struggling with this...
I'm trying to get the text of an li of game lobbies when I click on it.
There is an image to give you an idea of what I have:
[image]

These are my files:

gamelobby.component.html:

```
<h2>Game Lobbies</h2>

<div class='games'>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let m of gameLobby">{{m}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

gamelobby.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from '../services/websocket.service';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'gamelobby',
    styleUrls: [ 'gamelobby.component.css' ],
    templateUrl: 'gamelobby.component.html'
})
export class GameLobbyComponent implements OnInit{

    gameLobby: string[] = [];  
    mouseover:boolean = false;

    constructor(private websocketService: WebSocketService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.websocketService
            .getLobbies()
            .subscribe((m:any) => this.gameLobby.push(<string>m));
    }      
}
```

I have no clue how can I do it, I tried to do (click)="myMethod" to see if it would do something. But I did it wrong...

Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your `(click)="myMethod"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What if you try with something like:

```
<h2>Game Lobbies</h2>

<div class='games'>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let m of gameLobby" (click)="getValue(m)">{{m}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from '../services/websocket.service';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'gamelobby',
    styleUrls: [ 'gamelobby.component.css' ],
    templateUrl: 'gamelobby.component.html'
})
export class GameLobbyComponent implements OnInit{

    gameLobby: string[] = [];  
    mouseover:boolean = false;

    constructor(private websocketService: WebSocketService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.websocketService
            .getLobbies()
            .subscribe((m:any) => this.gameLobby.push(<string>m));
    }  

    getValue = (item : string) =>{
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time!

Answer (score 5):

You can just pass the `*ngFor` iteration variable:

```
<div class='games'>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let m of gameLobby" (click)="myMethod(m)">{{m}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
class GameLobbyComponent {
  myMethod(m) {
    console.log(m);
  }
}
```